# Getting WordPress post ID from within a filter

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a content_save_pre filter to update a custom field based on text in the content, e.g. [something]Thing[/something] will tell the plugin to set a custom field to "Thing".

My code (below) works fine when posting through the web interface, but fails on the clients I've tried (MarsEdit and WordPress iOS) and also the "Press This" bookmarklet. The [] tags get removed, but the custom field doesn't get set.

```
function dfll_get_link($post_content) {
  $dflink = dfll_find_link($post_content);
  if ($dflink) {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'linked_list_url', $dflink);
  }
  $temp = '/(' . dfll_regesc('[ll]') . '(.*?)' . dfll_regesc('[/ll]') . ')/i';
  $post_content = (preg_replace($temp, '', $post_content));
  return $post_content;
}

add_filter('content_save_pre', 'dfll_get_link');
```

From some testing, it seems that the $post_id variable isn't being set. Is there a way to get the post ID in these cases? Or should I try and add the filter to a different hook? (I can't think of any that fit, though.)

Comment: Not a solution per se, but you can try this patch: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15515

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, using Justin Blanton's [CF Setter](http://hypertext.net/projects/cfsetter) plugin. Extract the information and store as a global, then apply the setting as an action for save_post.

Comment: Can you expand on what the solution was, please?

Comment: Instead of trying to apply the filter directly, the author took the information, stored it in a global variable and did it as an action. Take a look at the CF Setter plugin source code, as it does exactly what I needed.